# dynamically add content to form in certain position

Tags: javascript, html, css

please have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLjF5/23/

Javascript

```
function addFields(rooms){
    var number = rooms;
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
        container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
    }
    for (i=1;i<number;i++){
        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        var input2 = document.createElement("input");
        input1.type = "text";
        input2.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("name room" + (i+1)));
        container.appendChild(input1);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("size room" + (i+1)));
        container.appendChild(input2);

    }
}
```

CSS

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.heading1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#">

    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="heading1">object</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="heading1">costs</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="heading1">funding</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="heading1">rooms</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2 class="heading1">reconstruction</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>street:</label>                  
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>costs:</label>                   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>term>:</label>                   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>name room 1:</label>                 
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <label>floor:</label>                   
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <input name="street" type="text" class="textbox" value="">  
    </div>  

    <div class="column">
        <input name="costs" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>      

    <div class="column">
        <input name="term" type="text" class="textbox" value="">    
    </div>          

    <div class="column">
        <input name="nameRoom1" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>  

    <div class="column">
        <input name="floor" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>      

    <div class="clear"> </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>date of purchase:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>power:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>interest:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>size room 1</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>walls:</label>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
        <input name="dateOfPurchase" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>


   <div class="column">
        <input name="power" type="text" class="textbox" value="">    
    </div>

     <div class="column">
        <input name="interest" type="text" class="textbox" value="">     
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <input name="sizeRoom" type="text" class="textbox" value="">     
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <input name="walls" type="text" class="textbox" value="">    
    </div>

                <div class="clear"> </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>number of rooms</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>water:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>residual value:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>parkingspot:</label>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <label>bath:</label>
    </div>


     <div class="column">
         <select name="roomsss" class="textbox" onchange="addFields(this.value)">
                                      <option>1</option>
                                      <option>2</option>
                                      <option>3</option>
                                      <option>4</option>
                                      <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <input name="water" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>      

    <div class="column">
        <input name="residualvalue" type="text" class="textbox" value="">   
    </div>          

    <div class="column">
        <input name="parkingspot" type="text" class="textbox" value=""> 
    </div>  

    <div class="column">
        <input name="bath" type="text" class="textbox" value="">    
    </div>  

    <div id="container"/>
```

I have a form in which you can select the number of rooms and for each room there will be a input field for size and name of the room.

the problem i experience is the location the script generates the new fields into. I have an extra column, the fourth, named rooms, where all the room information should be take place. so name/size for room 2 should be between room 1 and "parking spot" and so on. but, and this is very important to me: in case there is 1 room the "number of room selection" and "parking spot" are in the same row. if there is more than 1 room, this should not be the case anymore. the forth column should just add up all new elements an grow (downwards) independently from the other elements position.

would be really glad is someone could help me.
it is obviously also okay if you have an easier idea to structure the whole thing, this div-thing is my first shot.

Comment: Not answer but just a little bug `for (i=1;i<number;i++){` here `i` is going to be global variable you need to use `for (var i=1;i<number;i++){`

Comment: I noticed when you create your HTML in the `addFields` you just append them to the `div` with id `container` but without a wrapping `div` or assigning any classes so basically they are just being added to the container without any custom CSS.

Comment: IMO your HTML is jumbled, I think it would be better if each label was beside its corresponding text field. If you read your HTML top-down it doesn't make much sense. I would focus on fixing that first.